# How to get a video PHAsset disk file size?

Tags: avasset, phasset, photokit

I'm trying to determine the file size on disk of a PHAsset video.

The following code is returning am error "The file “IMG_0188.mov” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it."

```
PHVideoRequestOptions *options = [[PHVideoRequestOptions alloc] init];
            options.version = PHVideoRequestOptionsVersionOriginal;

            [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestAVAssetForVideo:asset options:options resultHandler:^(AVAsset *avAsset, AVAudioMix *audioMix, NSDictionary *info) {
                videoURL = [(AVURLAsset*)avAsset URL];

                NSNumber *videoDiskFileSize;
                NSError *error;
                [videoURL getResourceValue:&videoDiskFileSize forKey:NSURLFileSizeKey error:&error];

                if(error){
                    NSLog(@"ERROR %@", error.localizedDescription);
                }

                NSLog(@"size is %f",[videoDiskFileSize floatValue]/(1024.0*1024.0));
            }];
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's the correct way to do it.

```
PHVideoRequestOptions *options = [[PHVideoRequestOptions alloc] init];
            options.version = PHVideoRequestOptionsVersionOriginal;

            [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestExportSessionForVideo:asset options:options exportPreset:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality resultHandler:^(AVAssetExportSession *exportSession, NSDictionary *info) {
                CMTime videoDuration = CMTimeMultiplyByFloat64(exportSession.asset.duration, 1);
                exportSession.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoDuration);
                NSLog(@"Byyte size = %lld", exportSession.estimatedOutputFileLength);

                videoSize = exportSession.estimatedOutputFileLength;
            }];
```

Comment: Export is bad idea